# Is it possible to register one type for multiple keys with Autofac assembly scanning?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am trying to register on type (i.e. `MyClass`) for multiple Keys (i.e. 3, 4, 5) in AutoFac. 
So that, `componentContext.ResolveKeyed<T>(3)`,`componentContext.ResolveKeyed<T>(4)` and `componentContext.ResolveKeyed<T>(5)` all return `MyClass` instance.
I'm not sure how to do it as `Keyed<IMyClass>()` requires the type and not the values.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .Where(type => type.IsAssignableTo<IMyClass>())
            .Keyed<IMyClass>(type => type.GetCustomAttribute<MyCustomAttribute>().VALUES)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

[MyCustomAttribute(3, 4, 5)]
class MyClass : IMyClass { }

class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute {
    public int[] VALUES { get; set; }

    public MyCustomAttribute(params int[] values) {
       this.Values = values;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported in Autofac core, but you could easily make an extension method to do it for you.

```cs
public static IRegistrationBuilder<object, ScanningActivatorData, DynamicRegistrationStyle>
    Keyed<TService>(
        this IRegistrationBuilder<object, ScanningActivatorData, DynamicRegistrationStyle> registration,
        Func<Type, object[]> serviceKeyMapping)
{
    var serviceType = typeof(TService);
    return registration
        .AssignableTo(serviceType)
        .As(t => serviceKeyMapping(t).Select(key => new KeyedService(key, serviceType)));
}
```

It should be roughly a drop-in replacement for what you're trying to do.

Autofac is pretty easy to extend this way by using [the existing extension methods](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/develop/src/Autofac/RegistrationExtensions.cs) as a starting place for a lot of working examples. The one I put here is a very slight modification [on the existing `Keyed<T>` extension for assembly scanning.](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/53a10c1062bc4e959d2ef3d7ec3175ca735746ba/src/Autofac/RegistrationExtensions.cs#L538) Since not *every* use case can possibly be covered, this is the "official solution" for filling gaps like this.